# Off screen rendering textures with shaders

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, shader

I'm trying to figure out how to use shaders.

The code below just draws a circle in the center of a square image. To validate output the pixels are copying to .ppm image.

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <Math.h>


GLuint fbo, texture;
const int CHANNEL_COUNT = 4;
const GLenum PIXEL_FORMAT = GL_RGBA;

void init_gl(int width, int height);
void generate_fbo(int width, int height);
void draw_circle(float x, float y, float r = 0.5f);
void save_img(int w, int h, int data_size);

GLuint load_shaders(const char * v_s_path, const char * f_s_path);
GLuint init_simple_shader();
GLuint init_shader();

// -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- //

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int w = 512, h = 512;
    init_gl(w, h); // initialize GL resources

    // create frame buffer obeject and texture
    generate_fbo(w, h);

    //load shaders
    GLuint shader init_simple_shader(); // init_shader(); doesn't work 

    // draw a circle
    draw_circle(0, 0);
    save_img(w, h, w * h * CHANNEL_COUNT);

    // delete resources
    glDeleteProgram(shader);
    glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &texture);

    return 0;
}

// -*- -*- -*- -*- -*- //

void init_gl(int width, int height)
{
    glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL");

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
    float ar = (float)width / height;
    gluOrtho2D(-1*ar, ar, -1, 1);

    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);          
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}

GLuint init_simple_shader()
{
    //change texture color to red

    GLuint shader = load_shaders("./v_shader_simple.txt", "./f_shader_simple.txt");

    glUseProgram(shader);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    const float color[4] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}; // red color
    glUniform4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader, "color"), 1, color);

    return shader;
}

GLuint init_shader()
{
    //blur image

    GLuint shader = load_shaders("./v_shader.txt", "./f_shader.txt");

    glUseProgram(shader);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 );
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader, "texture"), 0);

    const float dir[2] = {1.0f, 0.0f};
    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(shader, "radius"), 0.1f);
    glUniform2fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader, "direction"), 2, dir);

    return shader;
}

void generate_fbo(int width, int height)
{

    // fbo
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

    // texture
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, PIXEL_FORMAT, width, height, 0, PIXEL_FORMAT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    //bind the texture to fbo
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);

    //Check for FBO completeness
    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE){
        std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();
        std::terminate();
    }
}

void draw_circle(float x, float y, float r)
{
    // just draw a circle with radial gradient brightness
    GLfloat angle;
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glColor3f(1.0f ,1.0f,1.0f);
    glVertex2f(x, y);
    glColor3f(0,0,0);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        angle = i * 2.0f * M_PI / 100;
        glVertex2f(x + cos(angle) * r, y + sin(angle) * r);
    }
    glEnd();
}

void save_img(int w, int h, int data_size)
{
    // get data from the frame buffer and save it like .ppm image
    std::vector<uint8_t> pixels(data_size);
    glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, PIXEL_FORMAT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &pixels[0]);

    FILE *f = fopen("./test_image.ppm", "wb");
    fprintf(f, "P6\n%i %i 255\n", w, h);
    for (int y=0; y< h; y++)
    {
        for (int x=0; x< w; x++)
        {
            int start_idx = (y * w + x) * CHANNEL_COUNT;
            fputc((int)pixels[start_idx], f);
            fputc((int)pixels[start_idx + 1], f);
            fputc((int)pixels[start_idx + 2], f);
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
}

GLuint load_shaders(const char * vertex_file_path,const char * fragment_file_path)
{

    // Create the shaders
    GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint FragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // Read the Vertex Shader code from the file
    std::string VertexShaderCode;
    std::ifstream VertexShaderStream(vertex_file_path, std::ios::in);
    if(VertexShaderStream.is_open()){
        std::string Line = "";
        while(getline(VertexShaderStream, Line))
            VertexShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
        VertexShaderStream.close();
    }else{
        printf("Impossible to open %s!\n", vertex_file_path);
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

    // Read the Fragment Shader code from the file
    std::string FragmentShaderCode;
    std::ifstream FragmentShaderStream(fragment_file_path, std::ios::in);
    if(FragmentShaderStream.is_open()){
        std::string Line = "";
        while(getline(FragmentShaderStream, Line))
            FragmentShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
        FragmentShaderStream.close();
    }

    GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
    int InfoLogLength;


    // Compile Vertex Shader
    printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", vertex_file_path);
    char const * VertexSourcePointer = VertexShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, &VertexSourcePointer , NULL);
    glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);

    // Check Vertex Shader
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    if ( InfoLogLength > 0 ){
        std::vector<char> VertexShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength+1);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
        printf("%s\n", &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    }



    // Compile Fragment Shader
    printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", fragment_file_path);
    char const * FragmentSourcePointer = FragmentShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(FragmentShaderID, 1, &FragmentSourcePointer , NULL);
    glCompileShader(FragmentShaderID);

    // Check Fragment Shader
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    if ( InfoLogLength > 0 ){
        std::vector<char> FragmentShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength+1);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
        printf("%s\n", &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    }

    // Link the program
    printf("Linking program\n");
    GLuint ProgramID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);
    glLinkProgram(ProgramID);

    // Check the program
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    if ( InfoLogLength > 0 ){
        std::vector<char> ProgramErrorMessage(InfoLogLength+1);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(ProgramID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
        printf("%s\n", &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
    }


    glDetachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
    glDetachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);

    glDeleteShader(VertexShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(FragmentShaderID);

    return ProgramID;
}
```

**Shaders (in .txt files)**
V.simple:

```
attribute vec2 coord; 
void main() 
{ 
    gl_Position = vec4(coord, 0.0, 1.0); 
}
```

F.simple:

```
uniform vec4 color; 
void main()
{ 
    gl_FragColor = color; // change the color
}
```

V.:

```
attribute vec2 TexCoord;
attribute vec4 Color;
attribute vec2 coord; 
varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

void main() 
{ 
    vColor = Color;
    vTexCoord = TexCoord;
    gl_Position = vec4(coord, 0.0, 1.0); 
}
```

F. (blur effect):

```
varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform float radius;
uniform vec2 dir;

void main() {
    vec4 sum = vec4(0.0);
    vec2 tc = vTexCoord;
    float hstep = dir.x;
    float vstep = dir.y;

    sum += texture2D(texture, vec2(tc.x - 4.0*radius*hstep, tc.y - 4.0*radius*vstep)) * 0.0162162162;
    sum += texture2D(texture, vec2(tc.x - 3.0*radius*hstep, tc.y - 3.0*radius*vstep)) * 0.0540540541;
    sum += texture2D(texture, vec2(tc.x - 2.0*radius*hstep, tc.y - 2.0*radius*vstep)) * 0.1216216216;
    sum += texture2D(texture, vec2(tc.x - 1.0*radius*hstep, tc.y - 1.0*radius*vstep)) * 0.1945945946;

    sum += texture2D(texture, vec2(tc.x, tc.y)) * 0.2270270270;

    sum += texture2D(texture, vec2(tc.x + 1.0*radius*hstep, tc.y + 1.0*radius*vstep)) * 0.1945945946;
    sum += texture2D(texture, vec2(tc.x + 2.0*radius*hstep, tc.y + 2.0*radius*vstep)) * 0.1216216216;
    sum += texture2D(texture, vec2(tc.x + 3.0*radius*hstep, tc.y + 3.0*radius*vstep)) * 0.0540540541;
    sum += texture2D(texture, vec2(tc.x + 4.0*radius*hstep, tc.y + 4.0*radius*vstep)) * 0.0162162162;

    gl_FragColor = vColor * vec4(sum.rgb, 1.0);
}
```

*How to compile on MacOS:*

```
c++ -std=c++11 -O3 -Wall -Wdeprecated-declarations -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL -framework Cocoa -o test main.cpp
```

The first simple shader *works well*: it just changes the texture color to red.
But the second one - unfortunately, doesn't. 
And I don't know why.

I have 3 assumptions where the bag is situated.

1. in the code which binding texture from shader to texture in frame buffer object.
2. the shader's code wrong.
3. both assumptions above simultaneously.

Render without shader:

[image: Render without shader]

Render with the simple shader:

[image: Render with the simple shader]

Render with the "blur effect" shader shows black screen...

Could anyone says what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you connect up your `TexCoord`, `Color`, & `coord` vertex attributes?  Why are you trying to inter-op fixed-function and programmable-pipline code?

Comment: @genpfault, _Why are you trying to inter-op fixed-function and programmable-pipline code?_ - I don't quite understand what do you mean?

Comment: You use `glColor3f` (fixed-function pipeline) to set the color and expect it to show up in the shader (programmable pipeline) -- but core OpenGL does not define any mapping between those. AFAIK NVidia provides some fixed mapping as an extension, but you cannot rely on that. You must create a VAO instead of using `glBegin`, `glEnd`, `glColor`, `glVertex` and `glTexCoord`.

Comment: Correction: [OpenGL 2 defined bulit-in variables to access fixed-function attributes from the shaders](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/attributes.php). However, you should rather use VAOs as I suggested.